# cfx_soap not giving response from web service

Tags: coldfusion

I am using cfx_soap tag in Cold Fusion to consume web service. But unable to get response.
The error is like 'java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1'

Comment: Please share relevant code to help you better.

Comment: I think I wrote CFX_Soap about 15-20 years ago. You really should consider updating the code to use something like createObject -- See an example of consuming a web service with it here: https://cfdocs.org/createobject

Comment: I tried createObject and cfInvoke, they both are unable to get the response, giving error like 'faultString: java.net.UnknownHostException: xyz123web'. But after enter that  entry for one IP in host file began to work, but I need dynamic IP of service as it is hosted on multiple servers

Comment: Could be that the WSDL for the service you are accessing is not pointing to the correct hostnames... Sounds like the problem is on the service end or DNS side of things.